# Can't SSH to machine behind NAT. (I know this is common, but I'm at the end of my rope here.)

Tags: networking, ssh, nat

I am using a Netgear WNR2000v5 router. The router itself has a static ip address, and is set up to utilize Network Address Translation. I have enabled port forwarding in the gui interface, and have verified that the SSH service at port xxx forwards to the same port on the local machine. I have also verified that the local machine has a reserved NAT local address which is unchanging. I have set `PasswordAuthentication yes`, and `AllowUsers <username>` within `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. And I have set `sshd:ALL` within `hosts.allow`. The firewall has been purged of all rules, and shows `policy ACCEPT` for `Chain INPUT`, `Chain FORWARD`, and `Chain OUTPUT`. (using iptables).

I am attempting to access the local machine behind the router from a laptop that is connected to a separate router, and hence is not on the local network, ensuring that the local NAT-based ip or hostname of the local machine is not used.

I am using the following commandline:

`ssh -p XXX <username(not root)>@XXX.XXX.XXX.X`

I still receive connection timed out. What on earth am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

(p.s. I know that from a security standpoint this is not optimal. Settings will be changed. Right now I'm just trying to get this thing to work.)

Comment: Who is your ISP? Are they using carrier grade NAT? How have you “verified” that the SSH service at port xxx forwards to the same port on the local machine? Have you tried connecting locally?  Is port ‘xxx’ equal to 22, because that is the port SSH listens on unless you changed it somewhere?

Comment: @Appleoddity A local broadband company. Disclosing their name would reveal my location. I don't know if they use carrier grade NAT. In the gui, I selected 'xxx' as the external and internal port on the rule that was saved in the port forwarding section of the NAT panel in the gui. I also changed the port used to the same value, 'xxx', in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Connecting locally succeeds. 'xxx' is not equal to 22.

Comment: I saw you had posted their name before editing it out. I was not able to look any information up prior to that. But the fact it is a small ISP suggests they may be using carrier grade NAT. You need to contact the ISP and see if they support your scenario. That is, hosting a server behind your public IP. You may find you have to purchase a different service or have them change things for you.